# How to trim a string in a specific way

Tags: python

Say I have a sentence such as:

> The bird flies at night and has a very large wing span.

My goal is to split the string so that the result comes out to be:

> and has a very large wing

I've tried using `split()`, however, my efforts have not been successful. How can I split the string into pieces, and delete the beginning part of the string and the end part?

Comment: Until you explain more of the logic that this is supposed to follow, the most anyone can do is provide the various ways to turn the input string into the output string (of which there are many).

Comment: You really should just use a _dedicated_ natural language processor. Such as [ntlk](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 My logic is to trim the given string of the words in front of the word 'and' and the words after 'large'. What would be the best approach to this solution?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a substring starting with the characters `and` and continuing until one (whitespace-delimited) word after the characters `large`? Your goal is still unclear. Perhaps you could edit your question to include the "efforts" you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = 'The bird flies at night and has a very large wing span.'
l = re.split(r'.+?(?=and)|(?<=wing).+?', text)[1]
```

out:

```
and has a very large wing
```

Comment: next time vote me down, please leave comment. I have no idea what's wrong with my code

Comment: Not a down-voter. My guess is it is due to the comment by OP *My logic is to trim the given string of the words in front of the word 'and' and the words after 'large'. What would be the best approach to this solution?* You are using hardcoded indexes

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri I get it. ths

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the best way to do what you want:

```
s = "The bird flies at night and has a very large wing span."
and_position = s.find("and") # return the first index of "and" in the string
wing_position = s.find("wing") # similar to the above
result = s[and_position:wing_position+4] # this is called python's slice
```

If you're not familiar with python slice, read more at [here](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/).